# how to disable outlook security pop-ups when sending emails via python

Tags: python, automation, outlook

I have a problem I am trying to automate the sending of emails using win32 in python.
The problem s that every time  when I run the code I get a security pop  [as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU2Lp.png)

[image]

How do i disable it

Comment: What did you learn when you clicked Help to find out how to avoid receiving that message?

Comment: All the options that are present there are not helping the first one is about updating  my antivirus, i am using a server and there is no anti virus, the other options are greyed out

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use Outlook to send the emails? Why not use SMTP directly, or send via the Exchange server (if that's what your organization is using)?

Comment: Other than that, there is likely one or more settings on the system that are generating this message. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the place to do that sort of debugging.

Comment: I have used smtp server for another project, maybe I will have to try and coy that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: you should not be sending messages by automating a message software, EVER.**

There are way better ways to send emails programatically:

- [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), for sending through standard SMTP:
- [exchangelib](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/), for sending using Exchange Web Services, for Microsoft 365 corporate inbox

But you've asked how to disable this security pop-up, and here is the answer, as explained in [the Microsoft Outlook help website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-email-message-on-your-behalf).

To disable this pop-up you should create a DWORD key named `ObjectModelGuard` in Windows registry. The folder will be one of:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office<x.0>\Outlook\Security` normally
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office<x.0>\Outlook\Security` if Outlook is running in 32-bit emulation from a 64-bit operating system (i.e. you are using a 32-bit build of Outlook in a 64-bit version of Windows).

You have to replace <x.0> with the specific version of Microsoft Office (16.0 = Office 2016, Office 2019, Office LTSC 2021, or Outlook for Microsoft 365, and 15.0 = Office 2013).

Set the key value to 2 to disable the warning, 0 for default behavior (only warns if an antivirus is not detected) or 1 to always warn.

If you need to, you could automate this behavior through Python, although you would require administrator rights to do so. Use [winreg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) to access the Windows registry through Python.